# problem eating solid food

Tags: toddler, food, eating

My daughter is now 2 years and 3 months. She eats most soft foods, like rice and soup, yogurt or soup that contains small pieces of vegetables. She is swallowing. But if I make the pieces a little bit bigger , she will throw it away.

Moreover, when it comes to solid food, she seems she doesn't know how to chew, chewing is a problem for her, she will try first to lick it and touch it with her tongue, then she will throw it away.

I tried everything even gummy sweets, cakes, or fruits or anything soft. I cut fruits into tiny pieces, but she is still licking it and throwing.
I don't give her milk at all, but she seems to be starving all day and depending on milk during the night, as she wakes up in the middle of the night asking for milk.

I tried to show her videos about children chewing and eating, I show her myself eating, we play games during eating, I have tried everything, since she was 1 year old.

Please help, any advice?

Comment: Hi Dima, welcome to Parenting.SE. We have a couple other questions on the site that may be relevant: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/21648/4054, http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/7235/4054 — do either of these sounds similar, or sound like the answers could help you reach a solution?